# EMPTY data inserted into the Android SQLITE table

Tags: sqlite

I have some doubts on my Programs. 
I'm UNABLE successfully insert date into my "producttable".

1. I can add into the table directly successfully  but not thru the
   "EDITTEXT". Once I click ADD.
2. The ID of the records do increase but the other column remains empty.
3. Following is the code of my program.

enter code here

+++Thanks+++

**stockmanagement.java**

```
package ping.stock.check;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import ping.stock.check.DBAdapter.DatabaseHelper;

import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator;
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentResult;

import android.R.id;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.*;
import android.database.*;




public class stockmanagement extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    Button button;
    final Context context = this;

    public Button scanBtn, AddBtn;
    public EditText proidTxt, pronameTxt, prounitTxt, prolowTxt, prorackTxt;

    DBAdapter DB = new DBAdapter(this);

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.stock_man);

        cleartextfield();
        tomenu();


        scanBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.SCANBttn);
        scanBtn.setOnClickListener(this);


        prounitTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.PRQTxt);
        prolowTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.LSATxt);


        AddBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ADDBttn);

        AddBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            String name = prounitTxt.getText().toString();
            String code = prolowTxt.getText().toString();

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) { 


                DB.open();
                //long id = DB.insertProduct("DATA1","DATA2");
                long id = DB.insertProduct(name, code);
                DB.close();
            }
        });

    }


    private void tomenu() {

        Button MMenuButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.MMENUBttn);
        MMenuButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent SMintent = new Intent(context, Welcome.class);
                startActivity(SMintent);
                stockmanagement.this.finish();

            }

        });     

    }


    public void cleartextfield() {
        Button CLRButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.CLRBttn);

        final EditText PRIDText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.PRIDTxt);
        final EditText PRNAMEText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.PRNAMETxt);
        final EditText PRQText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.PRQTxt);
        final EditText LSAText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.LSATxt);
        final EditText RACKText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.RACKTxt);

        CLRButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v){

                PRIDText.setText("");
                PRNAMEText.setText("");
                PRQText.setText("");
                LSAText.setText("");
                RACKText.setText("");   

            }
        });

    }   


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v.getId()==R.id.SCANBttn){
            IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
            scanIntegrator.initiateScan();
            }
        }       


    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);        
        if (scanningResult != null) {

            String scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();
            String scanFormat = scanningResult.getFormatName();

            pronameTxt.setText("FORMAT: " + scanFormat);
            proidTxt.setText("CONTENT: " + scanContent);

            }
        else{
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                "No scan data received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }

    }


}
```

**DBAdapter.java**

```
package ping.stock.check;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DBAdapter {

    static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    static final String KEY_NAME = "PRONAME";
    static final String KEY_CODE= "PROCODE";
    static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

    static final String DATABASE_NAME = "PINGSTOCKCHECKDATA";
    static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "producttable";
    static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

    public static final String DATABASE_CREATE = 
            "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE +"("
            + KEY_ROWID + "integer primary key autoincrement,"
            + KEY_NAME + "text not null,"
            + KEY_CODE + "text not null);";


    public final Context context;

    public DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
    public SQLiteDatabase DB;

    public DBAdapter (Context ctx){

        this.context = ctx;
        DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper (context);

    }

    public static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        DatabaseHelper (Context context){

            super (context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        try{    

            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);

        }

        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to " 
            + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS producttable");
            onCreate(db);

        }


    }
        // open the Database
        public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException {

            DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
            DB = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            return this;
        }   

        public void close(){

            DBHelper.close();
        }

        public long insertProduct(String name, String code) {

            ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
            initialValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);
            initialValues.put(KEY_CODE, code);

            return DB.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
        }
```

**stock_man.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tabletlayoutx" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="2"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_pic"

    >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRowx"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="5dip" >    

    </TableRow>

<ScrollView   
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<RelativeLayout

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    >

<TableLayout 

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"

    android:stretchColumns="2" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    </TableRow>

        <View
        android:layout_height="5dip"
        android:background="#FF0000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Stock Management"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#0000CC"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="monospace" />

    <View

        android:layout_height="5dip"
        android:background="#FF0001" />


    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="10dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="3dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="0dip"
            android:text="Product"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_width="5dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="3dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="0dip"
            android:text="Description"

            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="10dip "
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="4dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:text="ID No."
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/PRIDTxt"
            android:layout_width="5dip "
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="The Product ID"
            android:padding="5dip" 
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="30dip "
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="4dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/PRNAMETxt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="4dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="The Product Name"
            android:padding="5dip" 
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="10dip "
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="4dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:text="Unit"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/PRQTxt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="4dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Quantites (Number)"
            android:padding="0dip" 
            android:maxLength="9"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="4dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:text="Low Stock Alert"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/LSATxt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Alert for LOW STOCK"
            android:padding="0dip" 
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="10dip "
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="4dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:text="Rack No."
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/RACKTxt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="4dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Product Rack Location"
            android:padding="0dip" 
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/ADDBttn"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="1dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:text="ADD" 
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/CLRBttn"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="1dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:text="CLEAR" 
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow07"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/SCANBttn"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="1dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Scan" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
            android:id="@+id/MMENUBttn"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="1dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="MAIN MENU" 
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>

    </TableRow>

        <View
        android:layout_height="5dip"
        android:background="#FF0000" 
        />

</TableLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Hi, Code just added. Sorry and Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `getText()` on your edittexts too early when setting the `onClick()` listener. Move the `getText()` to `onClick()` itself to get the data on click.